# Why doesn't INSERT AFTER Trigger add all results?

Tags: trigger, sqlite

I'm working on the exercises for db-class.org where we have to write a trigger that makes new students named 'Friendly' automatically like everyone else in their grade. That is, after the trigger runs, we should have ('Friendly', A) in the Likes table for every other Highschooler A in the same grade as 'Friendly'.

This is being done in sqlite [on the following dataset](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dbclass-resources/docs/social.sql). Now my trigger works, but it only adds one person that 'Friendly' likes rather than all of them (those with the same grade).

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE Trigger Q1
After Insert on Highschooler
For Each Row
When New.Name = 'Friendly'
Begin
    INSERT Into Likes Values (New.ID, (
    SELECT Highschooler.ID FROM Highschooler
    WHERE Highschooler.Grade = New.Grade));
End;
```

I suspect there's something wrong with my INSERT query, because in isolation the SELECT returns all the IDs. **So how do I make sure it inserts all the IDs with matching grades?**

Comment: whats very interesting here is that SQLlite doesn't throw a SQL error IMO

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On most platforms your `insert` would throw an error if your subselect returns more than one row, rather than just insert the 'first' returned row (and 'first' is undefined without an `order by` clause).

What you are probably after is an `insert` like this:

```
INSERT Into Likes 
SELECT New.ID, ID 
FROM Highschooler 
WHERE Grade = New.Grade and ID<>New.ID;
```

Comment: Yep! This solves my problem, it inserts all combinations rather than just the first. Thanks!